# IIS/SQL Server showing RAM is 100% utilized but Processes add up to less than 15% usage

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, sql-server-2008

I have a Windows Server 2008 system running IIS 7 and SQL Server 2008 R2 with 64gb of RAM which is showing 100% of the available physical RAM being used at all times.

However, when you look at the memory usage via Task Manager and Process Explorer, all the processes (from all users) add up to less than 6gb of total RAM usage.

I'm trying to figure out what is using the remaining 58gb of RAM and I'm having trouble figuring it out.

Can anybody shed some light on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 32-bit or 64-bit?  If you are running 32-bit with AWE then it won't appear as in use by the SQL process.

Comment: 64-bit but I think I may have found the answer here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7060/sql-server-2008-r2-ghost-memory

Waiting to get access to SQL before I can run the queries but that matches what I found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer over here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7060/sql-server-2008-r2-ghost-memory

On the same page, there is a link to a blog post with an even great explanation: http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/09/sysadmins-guide-microsoft-sql-server-memory/